# swing how to clear JTable border?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I haed set like this; so help me about this;

```
topTable.setShowGrid (false);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V227o.png]

Answer (score 1):

That is the `Border` of the `JScrollPane`.

So try:

```
scrollPane.setBorder(null);
```

Comment: that is not useful,but i creat empt border and it is worked;

Comment: i have anorther question : how to modify column spacing?

Comment: *that is not useful* - Setting the Border null works on other components. Using an EmptyBorder should always work but is more to type. In any case it was helpful, since it pointed you in the right direction. *how to modify column spacing?* - read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Setting and Changing Column Widths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width)

Comment: i mean the column spacing can be changed ? not column width.

Comment: @haoli [setIntercellSpacing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#setIntercellSpacing(java.awt.Dimension))